# If $V(x_1,x_2) = V_1(x_1)+V(x_2)$ then $V$ is coercive iff $V_1,V_2$ are coercive.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, coercive

According to my notes $V$ is coercive iff $\lim_{\|x\| \to \infty} V(x) = +\infty$. I have been translating this as $\forall M \in \mathbb{R}. \exists R > 0.\|x\| > R \implies f(x) > M$.

But then I don't see what norms should I be taking to prove:

> If $V(x_1,x_2) = V_1(x_1)+V(x_2)$ then $V$ is coercive iff $V_1,V_2$
>   are coercive.

It seems really easy but I'm getting to the point of trying to find a counterexample (even if I think the proposition is true).

Comment: It applies to any norm.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Of course, but could you sketch the proof with any norm?

Comment: Your question contains a problem and a definition copied from your notes.  It would be better if you can give a start on either direction.  Say, "assume $V$ is coercive.  As $\|x_i\| \to \infty, \|x\| \to \infty$, so ..." or "assume $V_i$ are coercive.  As $\|x_i\| \to \infty, \|x\| \to \infty$, so $V = V_1 + V_2 = \cdots$"  P.S. Answers to PSQ are subject to deletion by CRUDE, so to avoid this, I'll avoid answering PSQ.